# gif image repeat play in html

Tags: gif, animated-gif

I want play repeatedly a gif file (as in liknk below) on a blog. what the code I have to put on the page
http://i57.photobucket.com/albums/g223/sadeedp/Football/mardna.gif

Answer (score 9):

That's defined within the GIF itself.
You have to edit the GIF file to enable endless animation loop.

Comment: how can I edit the GIF in order to make it endless animation loop

Comment: An image editor of your choice. may be Gimp can do this.